# Incompatible pointer types (double pointers)

Tags: c, pointers, double-pointer

In a function that asks a double pointer like this one:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void    prueba(void **ap)
{
    *ap = NULL;
}
```

compiled with the following main:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void    prueba(void **ap);

int        main(void)
{
    char *str;

    str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
    prueba(&str);
    if (str == NULL)
        printf("NULL");
    return (0);
}
```

I get this warning with gcc:

```
main2.c:11:9: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char **' to parameter of type 'void **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        prueba(&str);
               ^~~~
main2.c:4:23: note: passing argument to parameter 'ap' here
void    prueba(void **ap);
```

But if i do the same but with simple pointers, that is give a pointer to char to a function who asks for a void pointer, gcc compiles without warnings, for example, the following compiles right:
function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void    prueba(void *ap)
{
    ap = NULL;
}
```

main:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void    prueba(void *ap);

int        main(void)
{
    char *str;

    str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
    prueba(str);
    if (str == NULL)
        printf("NULL");
    return (0);
}
```

So my question is, why it works with simple pointers but it does not work with double pointers (or greater i guess)?

Comment: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/genericpp.html

Comment: 1. Why are you using void pointers? 2. Why are you casting `malloc`?

Comment: Any pointer implicitly converts to a void*.  The same is not true for a void**.

Comment: A pointer to a `char *` is not the same type as a pointer to a `void *`.

Comment: i used an example i have, i just want to know about the warning when a function that asks for void double pointer gets a char double pointer

Comment: In C, do not cast the result of a call to `malloc()`, `realloc()`, or `calloc()` - it is unnecessary and potentially hides the serious error of a missing prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C Standard (6.3.2.3 Pointers)

> 1 A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any
>   object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a
>   pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the
>   original pointer.

So in the second code snippet a pointer of the type `char *` is implicitly converted to the type `void *` though the function does not make sense because it deals with a copy of its argument and therefore does not changes the original pointer.

However the type `void **` is not the same as the type `void *`. So the quote is not applicable for the type `void **` and the compiler issues a diagnostic message because there is no implicit conversion from a pointer to any object type to a pointer of the type `void **`.

Answer (score 2):

A `void *` can freely be assigned to or from any object pointer freely.  This freedom does *not* extends to `void **`, as that is a distinct type.

Also, your fixed program won't work as expected, since `ap = NULL;` only changes the local variable inside of `prueba` and not the parameter passed in.

Change your original program to accept a `char **` instead of a `void **`.